# Why scattering of red and blue quark only involves $G_8^\mu$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

According to the author C. G. Tully (Particle physics in a nutshell), the scattering of a red and blue quark only involves $G_8^\mu$. How come this is so?

I thought $G_3^\mu$ and $G_8$ only mediate between quarks of the same color?

If we consider the following term which comes from the interaction term of QCD:

$$\bar{q}{\not}Dq\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{r}\bar{g}\bar{b}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}{\not}G_3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}{\not}G_8 & {\not}G_{r\bar{g}} & {\not}G_{r\bar{b}} \\
{\not}G_{g\bar{r}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}{\not}G_3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}{\not}G_8 &  {\not}G_{g\bar{b}}\\[3pt]
{\not}G_{b\bar{r}} & {\not}G_{b\bar{g}}  &  -\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}{\not}G_8 \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r \\ g \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we will get that a term involving a red and a blue quark will be associated with the off-diagonal terms ${\not}G_{r\bar{b}}, {\not}G_{b\bar{r}}, \dots$.

Comment: We can always rotate $G$ into the Cartan subalgebra (which is spanned by $G_3$ and $G_8$) of the gauge group by a gauge transformation. How does the interaction term look, then? (Not an answer because I haven't done the math to check if the statement comes out)